# ERROR:System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In General, for some reason, when you run Publish as a standalone Win x64 application,

> the Sql client error is not supported on this platform

, although if you run it from under VS, everything is fine.

.Net Core is version 2.2 with the latest available lib versions for working with Sql Server.

What could be the problem?

At first, I sinned by trying to perform migrations in a startup. cs, but after cutting it out, I started falling with the same error when trying to subtract data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just edit project file and problem was solved:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifier> --Add new platform
    <IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>true</IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>
    <UserSecretsId>ed6862ca-e455-4714-9552-bff6407b2370</UserSecretsId>   </PropertyGroup>
```